# Can I extend an @Component and create another @Component class and make only one available at a time?

Tags: java, spring-boot, inheritance

I have a library jar which I want to provide to a number of applications. The behavior I want is to create a common spring component class in the library. If in the applications, the same component is not extended then use the common component; if it's extended in the app, then use the extended component (child class). Is this possible? - Create CommonComponent only if a child for that class doesn't exist.

I am using Java 1.8, Springboot2.0

Created class in library:

```
@Component
public class CommonComponent{}
```

In one of the child apps using the library, I added a child component:

```
@Component
public class ChildComponent extends CommonComponent{}
```

I expected one component ChildComponent created; but in the above scenario 2 components - CommonComponent and ChildComponent are created.

Comment: There might be a Configuration that specify the package to scan. put your CommonComponent in another package. What is the need of having @component on CommonComponent? couldn't it be an abstract class?

Comment: @Pdem They stated that CommonComponent is a concrete class, as it could be used in the case a child class doesn't exist. So it can't be abstract...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way you could do this is to take advantage of the [`@ConditionalOnMissingBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html) annotation that Spring Boot has. When combined with a bean definition in a `@Configuration` class, we can tell Spring to only define our bean if it doesn't already have one.

This is untested:

```
@Configuration
public class CustomComponentConfiguration {

    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(CustomComponent.class)
    @Bean
    public CustomComponent customComponent() {
        return new CustomComponent();
    }
}
```

In this example, when our `@Configuration` runs, Spring determines if there is any other bean that is a `CustomComponent`. If not, it executes the `customComponent()` method and defines whatever bean you return. So if somebody else defines a `ChildComponent`, this method will not get called.

Comment: Thank you so much Todd. This worked for me. I had to remove the @Component from the parent class though (CommonComponent class).  I added the configuration class like this: ```@Configuration
public class CustomComponentConfiguration {

    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    @Bean
    public CommonComponent commonComponent() {
        return new CommonComponent();
    }
}```

Answer (score 3):

when you are creating the child component put `@Primary` annotation

> Indicates that a bean should be given preference when multiple candidates are qualified to autowire a single-valued dependency

so you'll have

```
@Primary
@Component
public class ChildComponent extends CommonComponent { /* ... */ }
```

and in your services autowire `CommonComponent` type and spring will inject `ChildComponent` or `CommonComponent`

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I tried this; but it will work only if I have to autowire the component somewhere. What I am creating is a Filter component and so I am not autowiring it anywhere in the code explicitly.

Comment: Autowire it into the class where you are creating the filter